# include a cent-sensitive character that does not interfere with the delimiter of a csv file

Tags: awk, sed, csv

I have a CSV file that I need to include a separator to highlight the cents in that column that doesn't interfere with the ',' delimiter

Below is the model of how my current file is:

```
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0090922002,000000000009102629-,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0091000002,000000000063288833+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0091100005,000000000063288833-,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0091110002,000000000063288833-,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0099999995,000000008017897139+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
```

As the file delimiter is ',' I believe the '.' be cool to use. How can I leave the file like this?

```
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0090922002,0000000000091026.29-,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0091000002,0000000000632888.33+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0091100005,0000000000632888.33-,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0091110002,0000000000632888.33-,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0099999995,0000000080178971.39+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
```

Comment: If you quote the field, you can use embedded commas: `...,"0000000000091026,29-",...`. This would be readable by any CSV parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `substr()`:

```
awk -F, '$5 = substr($5,1,length($5)-3) "." substr($5,length($5)-2)' OFS=,
```

Answer (score 2):

If using awk is not mandatory, using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/), if you want the comma as decimal separator

```
mlr --csv -N put -S '$5=sub($5,"(...)$",",\1")' input.txt
```

gives you

```
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0090922002,"0000000000091026,29-",000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0091000002,"0000000000632888,33+",000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0091100005,"0000000000632888,33-",000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0091110002,"0000000000632888,33-",000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0099999995,"0000000080178971,39+",000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
```

If you want the dot as decimal separator

```
mlr --csv -N put -S '$5=sub($5,"(...)$",".\1")' input.txt
```

```
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0090922002,0000000000091026.29-,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0091000002,0000000000632888.33+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0091100005,0000000000632888.33-,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0091110002,0000000000632888.33-,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0099999995,0000000080178971.39+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {sub(/...$/,".&",$5)} 1' file
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0090922002,0000000000091026.29-,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0091000002,0000000000632888.33+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0091100005,0000000000632888.33-,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0091110002,0000000000632888.33-,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0099999995,0000000080178971.39+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/[0-9]\{2\}[+-],/.&/' input_file
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0090922002,0000000000091026.29-,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0091000002,0000000000632888.33+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0091100005,0000000000632888.33-,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0091110002,0000000000632888.33-,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
99999999,2021-01-01,I,0099999995,0000000080178971.39+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
```

Comment: @EdMorton Indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use awk, GoCSV's [replace](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv#replace) command can handle this:

```bsh
gocsv replace -c 5 -regex '(\d{2}[+-])' -repl '.$1' input.csv
```

Actually, because your sample doesn't have a header, we'll need to add a header (cap), do the replace, then remove header (behead):

```bsh
gocsv cap --default-name 'Col' input.csv |
gocsv replace -c 5 -regex '(\d{2}[+-])' -repl '.$1' | 
gocsv behead
```